# [Docker][syslog-ng] Getting the error: "docker: invalid reference format"

Tags: docker, syslog-ng

I'm very new to Docker and this is my first project.
I'm trying to create a centralized syslog server using docker container and syslog-ng.
I have modified the syslog-conf file so that it writes to a particular file location on the host machine.

For testing purposes, I am trying to re-route logs from nginx to /var/log of syslog-ng.

docker run -p 514:514 -p 601:601 –name mysyslog -d -v /Users/Desktop/syslogng/syslog-ng.conf:/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf -v /usr/local/var/log/nginx:/var/log balabit/syslog-ng:latest --no-caps

When I run this command, I'm getting the exception: 
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Your command has a invalid character on it (the hyphen), did you copy/paste from somewhere?

You have `–name` where it should be `--name`.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I meant to write --name. 

--name gave the same exception: docker: invalid reference format.

And I did copy/paste it from another file where I had saved some commands.
Weirdly enough, when I deleted the hyphens and retyped it, it seems to work! 
Thank you for your response!